# How to prove this expression of lower semi-continuouss?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

The definition of lower semi-continuous in wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) is
\begin{equation}
\mathop{\lim\inf}_{x\to x_{0}} f(x)\ge f(x_0).
\end{equation}
However, in some books, inequality is changed to equation, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\mathop{\lim\inf}_{x\to x_{0}} f(x) = f(x_0).
\end{equation}
I don't know the latter one is right or not, and i can't give a counterexample to prove that it is incorrect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the definition of $\liminf_{x\to x_0}$. If you use 
$$
\liminf_{x\to x_0} f(x) := \lim_{r\to 0} \inf \left\{ f(x): d(x,x_0)<r, x\ne x_0  \right\}
$$
then strict inequality could happen. For example, the function
$$
f(x)=\cases{0 &; $x=0$\\ 1 &; $x\in\Bbb R\backslash\{0\}$}
$$
is lower semicontinuous at $x=0$ but $\liminf_{x\to 0} f(x)=1> 0 = f(0)$.

However, if your definition does not have the restriction $x\ne x_0$, i.e. 
$$
\liminf_{x\to x_0} f(x) := \lim_{r\to 0} \inf \left\{ f(x): d(x,x_0)<r  \right\}
$$
then we can write $\liminf_{x\to x_{0}} f(x) = f(x_0)
$
because we'd have $\inf \left\{ f(x): d(x,x_0)<r  \right\}\le f(x_0)$ which implies that the equality sign actually holds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it.

Comment: For some references where non-deleted neighborhoods are used in defining $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ (your second formulation), see my comment to [Question about the definition of lim sup and lim inf on real valued functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887228).

Comment: Since my comment from 5 August 2014 didn't specify the books sufficiently for someone not already familiar with them, I'll be more specific here: [**Theory of Functions of a Real Variable**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0019CL610) by I. P. Natanson (Volume II, 1960, pp. 149-150) *AND* [**Theory of Functions of Real Variables**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0007HLGTU) by Henry P. Thielman (1953, pp. 99-100) *AND* [**Introduction to Real Functions and Orthogonal Expansions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0195010744) by Béla Sz.-Nagy (1965, pp. 54-58).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you, I didn't really know the source for these different formulations. I only recalled that my professor told me about the existence of another one.

Comment: I *might* have seen this ambiguity many years ago, but in recent years I became aware of this ambiguity when I was preparing for [a talk I that gave in October 2013](http://iamaa.alhibbard.com/tools/index.php/proposal/viewPublic/370), and at one point I spent maybe a frantic hour the day before (when I wrote the slides for the talk; before this I had only made some very brief outline notes), trying to resolve an inconsistency that I was coming up with for some basic properties of semi-continuous functions. **(continued)**

Comment: I finally realized, and yes it took me about an hour (!!) because **I thought I was doing something wrong**, that the inconsistency had to do with the fact that a few books I had consulted used a different definition of $\liminf$ and $\limsup,$ something that I didn't consider would be the case until after about an hour of panic.

Comment: I can safely say that I have seen more than 4 different notions of _upper semicontinuity_ for multifunctions...