# Different definition of lower semi-continuity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

I am struggling to understand how different definitions of lower semi-continuity compare to each other. I am mostly concerned with that concept regarding closed convex functions.

Therefore I am reading several books on convex analysis and get the following definitions:

1.) In the book "Convex Analysis" by Rockafeller, he defines lower semi-continuity as follows:

An extended-real-valued function $f$ given on $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be lower semi-continuous at a point $x$ of $S$ if:

$$f(x) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$$

for any sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ that converges to $x$ and the limit of $f(x_1), f(x_2), ... $ exists in $[-\infty, +\infty]$.

This condition may be expressed as:

$$f(x)= \liminf_{y \to x} f(y)=\lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0}(\inf{f(y)\mid |x-y|\leq \varepsilon}).$$

2.) Then in the book Fundamentals of Convex Analysis we have the definition:

A function $f$ is lower semi-continuous if, for each $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$,

$$ \liminf_{y \to x} f(y) \geq f(x)$$

This relation has to hold in $\mathbb{R} \cup {+\infty}$ (i.e., they exclude $-\infty$ here).

3.) In the book by Bertskas, the definition is:

Recall that $f$ (where $f: X\rightarrow [-\infty, +\infty]$) is called lower semi-continuous at a vector $x \in X$ if

$$f(x)\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) $$

So my questions are as follows:

i) I can see that the Definitions 2) and 3) are the same. But how do they relate to 1)? Is 1) the same as 2) and 3) under certain conditions? I would say that 2) and 3) are not the same as 1) but in all three books they prove that their definition of lower semicontinuity is equivalent to the epigraph being closed and all sublevel sets being closed. So that would actually imply that their respective definitions of semi-continuity are also the same.

ii) Does the value $-\infty$ play a role in whether we need an inequality or an equality?

iii) How does Rockafeller in 1) get from his definition via an inequality to an equality?

iv) In fundamentals of convex analysis they define the closure of a function $f$ the function $cl(f): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ as:

$$(cl(f))(x)= \liminf_{y \to x} f(y)$$

and say that this is equivalent to

$$epi(cl(f)) = cl(epi(f)).$$

How can we see that this is equivalent? (I think this only holds for proper convex functions though, as they only treat these in the book)

Comment: Rockafellar defines liminf different than what is (now?) the standard (i.e., wikipedia). So he gets a different lower-semicontinuity condition. Also, $-\infty$ is not special when it comes to these conditions. (iv) is a new question in itself.

Comment: But how is it possible that both the definition of Rockafeller and of the other books are eqivalent with the epigraph being closed? I mean that would imply that the two definitions for semicontinuouity are equivalent too, no?

Comment: Assuming what @daw says is appropriate here (I'm just passing by quickly and don't have time to say more), then maybe my comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/887228/13130) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3031003/13130) will help.

Comment: The definitions of lower semicontinuity are equivalent, but the definitions of liminf are not.

Comment: Okay so but what I then dont understand is why the definition regarding sequences differ between definition 1) from Rockafeller and 3). Because in his definition with sequences, Rockafeller uses the normal limes not the lim inf, so here the fact that Rockafeller seems to use a different definition of lim inf doesnt even come into play, right? So how can the two definitions using sequences be equivalent?

Comment: What does $epi$ mean?

Comment: epi means the epigraph of a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rockafeller defines that $f : S \to [-\infty,+\infty]$ is lower semi-continuous at $x \in S$ if

$$f(x) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \text{ for any sequence } (x_n) \text{ in } S \text{ converging to } x \\ \text{ such that the limit of } (f(x_n)) \text{ exists in } [-\infty, +\infty] . \tag{1}$$
The claim

> This condition may be expressed as $f(x)= \liminf_{y \to x} f(y)$

is not true if we use the standard definition of $\liminf$ which is
$$\liminf_{y \to x} f(y) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} I(f,x,\epsilon)$$ with $I(f,x,\epsilon) = \inf f( S \cap B(x,\epsilon) \setminus \{x\})$.

However, Rockafeller uses the follwing unusual definition which I denote by $\liminf^*$ for the sake of clarity:

$${\liminf}^*_{y \to x} f(y) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} I^*(f,x,\epsilon)$$
with $I^*(f,x,\epsilon) = \inf f(S \cap B(x,\epsilon))$.

Note that $f(S \cap B(x,\epsilon)) = f(S \cap B(x,\epsilon)  \setminus \{x\}) \cup \{f(x)\}$, thus
$$I^*(f,x,\epsilon) = \min(I(f,x,\epsilon), f(x) $$
and therefore
$${\liminf}^*_{y \to x} f(y)  = \min({\liminf}_{y \to x} f(y) , f(y)) .$$

Hence Rockafeller's $f(x) = {\liminf}^*_{y \to x} f(y)$ means nothing else than
$$f(x) \le \liminf_{y \to x} f(y) . \tag{2}$$

Note that in general $\liminf_{y \to x} f(y) > {\liminf}^*_{y \to x} f(y)$. As an example consider the function $f : \mathbb R \to [-\infty,+\infty], f(x) = 1$ for $x \ne 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. We have $\liminf_{y \to 0} f(y) = 1 > 0 = {\liminf}^*_{y \to 0} f(y)$.

We shall prove that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(2)$.

Observe that $I(f,x,\epsilon') \ge I(f,x,\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon' \le \epsilon$. Thus

1. $\liminf_{y \to x} f(y) \ge I(f,x,\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.
2. $\liminf_{y \to x} f(y) = -\infty$ if and only if $I(f,x,\epsilon)  = -\infty$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.
3. If $(\epsilon_n)$ is any sequence of positive numbers converging to $0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} I(f,x,\epsilon_n) = \liminf_{y \to x} f(y)$.

$(1) \implies (2)$:

Let us first consider the case $\liminf_{y \to x} f(y) = -\infty$. Then $I(f,x,1/n)  = -\infty$ for all $n$.  We can therefore pick $x_n \in S \cap B(x,1/n) \setminus \{x\}$ such that $f(x_n) < -n$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)  = -\infty$. From $(1)$ we conlude that $f(x) = -\infty$, thus $(2)$ is satisfied.

If $\liminf_{y \to x} f(y)  > -\infty$, we know that $I(f,x,\epsilon_0) > -\infty$ for some $\epsilon_0 > 0$. Hence $I(f,x,\epsilon) \ge I(f,x,\epsilon_0) > -\infty$ for all $\epsilon \le \epsilon_0$. Pick $x_n \in S \cap B(x,\epsilon_0/n) \setminus \{x\}$ such that $f(x_n) < I(f,x,\epsilon_0/n) + 1/n$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} I(f,x,\epsilon_0/n) = \liminf_{y \to x} f(y)$. Thus $(1)$ shows  $f(x) \le \liminf_{y \to x} f(y) $.

$(2) \implies (1)$:

If $f(x) = -\infty$, then $(1)$ is trivially satisfied. So let $f(x) > -\infty$. Then $(2)$ excludes $\liminf_{y \to x} f(y) =-\infty$.  Consider any sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ converging to $x$ such that $(f(x_n))$ converges to some $\eta \in [-\infty,\infty]$. If $\eta = \infty$, we are done. If infinitely many $x_n = x$, we must have $\eta = f(x)$ and we are done again. So let us consider the case that only finitely many $x_n = x$. Assume that $f(x) > \eta$, i.e. $r = f(x) - \eta > 0$. Then $f(x) - r/2 > f(x_n)$ for $n \ge n_0$. Clearly each $S \cap B(x,\epsilon) \setminus \{x\}$ contains infinitely many $x_n$, thus $I(f,x, \epsilon) < f(x) - r/2 $ and thus $\liminf_{y \to x} f(y) \le f(x) - r/2$ which contradicts $(2)$.

**Update:**

Bertskas defines that $f : S \to [-\infty,+\infty]$ is lower semi-continuous at $x \in S$ if

$$f(x) \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \text{ for any sequence } (x_n) \text{ in } S \text{ converging to } x . \tag{3}$$

$(3) \implies (1)$:

Consider a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$ exists and has the value $\eta \in[-\infty,+\infty]$. Then $\liminf_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \eta = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$ because $\eta$ is the only accumulation point of $(f(x_n))$. Thus from $(3)$ we get $f(x) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$.

$(1) \implies (3)$:

Let $(x_n)$ be any sequence converging to $x$ and $\eta =  \liminf_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$. There exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = \eta$. Since clearly $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$, $(1)$ applies to give $f(x) \le \lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = \eta$. Thus $f(x) \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$.

Comment: thanks for you anwer. Some ppl have commented under my question that Rockafeller uses a different definition of liminf. I am not sure if that is true or not but I have edited my question to specify how Rockafeller defines liminf. Is that definition in fact different from the common definition? And if so, does it follow that the two definitions of Rockafellar are indeed equivalent?

Comment: @guest1 Okay. I made an update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I m still digesting it. 
So just for my understanding: The definition of Rockafellars liminf combined with the equal sign is actually equivalent to the usual definition of liminf with a smaller or equal sign?
And then you also show that Def (1) and (2) are equivalent right? 
So then my brief question would be if I am correct in my assumption that (2) and (3) are anyway equivalent?

Comment: One thing I am still unsure about though is: How can the definition of Rockafellar with the sequences be equivalent to the definition of (3) with sequences. Since Rockafellar uses a normal limes and (3) uses liminf and other than that the definitions seem to be the same

Comment: @guest1 "The definition of Rockafellars liminf combined with the equal sign is actually equivalent to the usual definition of liminf with a smaller or equal sign". No, Rockafellar's definition of $\lim inf$ is not equivalent to the standard one. We have ${\liminf}^*_{y \to x} f(y) = \min({\liminf}_{y \to x} f(y) , f(y)$. BUT Rockafellar's definition of semicontinuity based on ${\liminf}^*_{y \to x} f(y)$ and equal sign is equivalent to  the definition of semicontinuity based on ${\liminf}_{y \to x} f(y)$ and smaller or equal sign. Yes to your other question.

Comment: @guest1 I guess in 3.) it is required that $f(x)\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) $ for all sequences converging to $x$?

Comment: yes exactly this has to hold for all sequences in X converging to x

Comment: @guest1 See my update.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I have 2 questions left to your answer:
in (1) ==> (2) you follow from $f(x_n) < -n$ that $\lim f(x_n) = -\infty$, however we have $\lim f(x_n) <\lim-n =-\infty$ which can not happen right?

The other question is in (2)==>(1): what happens in the scenario where there is no $x_n=x$?

Comment: @guest1 Q1: It seems that you believe $a_n < b_n$ implies $\lim a_n< \lim b_n$.  **This is not true**. We only have  $\lim a_n \le \lim b_n$. Another example is $a_n = -1/n$ and $b_n = 1/n$. Q2: If no $x_n = x$, then certainly only finitely many $x_n=x$.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help!